# Understanding Kernel Mean Embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing

I was learning about kernel mean embeddings.  I was under the impression that the mean embedding was just the mean of a function with respect to a probability distribution.  Then I saw somewhere that if you have a "one-hot" representation of a distribution the kernel embedding becomes a vector.  Is this true?  How can you use these mean embeddings like in SVMs or Ridge Regressions if they are vectors.